# Can't install Firebug in FF8, "can't modify the file", how to fix?

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, firebug

I try installing FireBug in FF8, apparently it downloads it correctly, but reports an error when installing. No debug information is shown, just "can't modify the file". How can I debug this installation in Ubuntu (Xubuntu, 11.10)? If it's just user rights issue, it should not be a problem.

Answer (score -1):

5) [FAQ - FirebugWiki: Installation Issues](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/FAQ#Installation_Issues)

5.3) [Can't Install Firebug on Windows](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/FAQ#Can.27t_Install_Firebug_on_Windows)

> Installation Issues
>
> Compatibility Firebug 1.9 will work with Firefox 6.0 up to Firefox 9.*
>   (or higher) Firebug 1.8 works with Firefox 5.0 up to Firefox 7.*
>   Firebug 1.7 works with Firefox 3.6 up to Firefox 5.*, see however
>   known issues. Firebug 1.6 works with Firefox 3.6 Firebug 1.5 works
>   with Firefox 3.5 and Firefox 3.6 Firebug 1.4 works with Firefox 3.0 up
>   to Firefox 3.6 (1.4.4) Firebug 1.3 works with Firefox 1.5 (1.3.0) up
>   to Firefox 3.0 Firebug 1.2 works with Firefox 2.0 and Firefox 3.0
>   Firebug 1.0 works with Firefox 1.5 and Firefox 2.0 Firebug Lite works
>   with IE, Safari, and Opera Please visit AMO for a full version
>   history. [edit] Installing in a clean profile To test for bugs
>   regarding interactions with other extensions or corrupted profiles,
>   you should do the following. Firefox and Firebug re-install rarely
>   fixes problems because the configuration files are not altered on
>   reinstall. So to clear out the configuration files you need to create
>   a new Firefox profile: [edit] Linux Way Exit Firefox Get to a command
>   line Run Firefox with -ProfileManager  $ firefox -ProfileManager
>   Create New Profile Start Firefox with your new profile Load Firebug
>   into this clean profile. [edit] Windows Way Exit Firefox Get to a
>   command line Windows: Start->Run->"cmd" enter Run Firefox with
>   -ProfileManager (use quotes around the file name because of the spaces)  "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
>   -ProfileManager Create New Profile Start Firefox with your new profile Load Firebug into this clean profile. Read more about this on Mozilla
>   Support "Managing Profiles" [edit] Can't Install Firebug on Windows
>   Sometimes Firebug just won't get installed in Firefox using Windows.
>   The first thing to try is a new Firefox profile above. If that fails
>   you can dig deeper. Here are some recommended actions to take: With
>   Firefox closed, locate your profile directory, delete these temporary
>   files, they will be automatically re-created by Firefox:
>   extensions.ini extensions.cache extensions.rdf compreg.dat Disable any
>   Antivirus or BackUp program you may have running and then install
>   Firebug. It may be that some software is stopping Firefox creating the
>   file structures needed for the installation process. Run Firefox as
>   Administrator. It may be the same as in reason 2, because firefox
>   doesn't have enough permissions. Manually install Firebug. This can be
>   done easily, just unzip the XPI (it's a normal zipped file with the
>   extension changed) in your extensions folder, inside your profile. You
>   should unzip firebug's XPI content inside a folder named
>   'firebug@software.joehewitt.com'. Do this with Firefox closed. To get
>   the XPI go to Firebug on Addons.Mozilla.Org, right click on the "Add
>   to Firefox" button and select "Save Link As...".

Comment: Dunno why the formatting is screwed when I copy and paste in =S

Comment: CodeBlend, SuperUser.com uses [MarkDown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) to format text. When you pasted, the `textarea` outputed the plaintext (as opposed to HTML). This plaintext is not in MarkDown, so the original formatting did not persist.

Comment: @iglvzx ah did wonder, thanks, um how do I get normal formatting in there, for example three lines of text one after the other with only one return carriage?

Comment: Add an extra line between them, while keeping any indentation. :)

Comment: The link was useful, but I use **Ubuntu**, not Windows.

Comment: There is some information for Linux (Ubuntu), where there isn't I believe Google should show you the Linux equivelant =)